# Type of data output from a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

May be a silly question but i am confused how do programmers know that the output datatype is a dataframe or a numpy array and which corresponding methods should be used. For e.g. Here we read the csv file using pd.read_csv which results in a dataframe.

```
d0 = pd.read_csv('train.csv') # MNIST train database (https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data)
l = d0['label']
d = d0.drop('label', axis = 1)
```

so here d0 is `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, d is also `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
standard_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(d)
print(type(standard_data))
```

But how come the type of data is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: pd = pandas.  Of course a pandas function to read data will return a pandas dataframe. We can look at the [documentation of the fit_transform method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) to see that it returns a numpy array

Comment: In general `numpy` and `scipy` functions return `ndarray`.  If given a `DataFrame` or `Series` they convert the input to array, e.g. `np.asarray(arg)` (which in turn uses `df.to_numpy()`).  I believe some `sklearn` functions do return `pandas` objects, but this, at least, does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know by either printing the type as you have done, or by Googling for the docs of the function you are using.

See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) for the docs on the `fit_transform` method, which says:

> Returns X_new: ndarray array of shape (n_samples, n_features_new)

As a general rule of thumb, `pd` is pandas and returns a pandas Dataframe, whilst `np` and `sklearn` usually use numpy arrays.